# Use calendarItemWithIdentifier to lookup calendar event

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, eventkit

I'm trying to lookup a calendar event by the new iOS method calendarItemWithIdentifier. I can't use the eventWithIdentifier because the identifier is changed after the event is syncronized with the server. The calendarItemIdentifier is not.

But the calendarItemWithIdentifier always returns (null).

```
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {

        // Create event.
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = self.title;
        event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
        event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:7200];
        event.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

        BOOL success = [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
        if (success)
        {
            NSString *calendarItemIdentifier = event.calendarItemIdentifier;
            NSLog(@"Assigned identifier: %@", calendarItemIdentifier);

            // Look up the event in the calendar.
            event = (EKEvent *)[store calendarItemWithIdentifier:calendarItemIdentifier];
            if (event) {
                NSLog(@"FOUND");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"NOT FOUND");
            }
        }
    }

}];
```

From the log:

```
2013-01-13 10:32:52.042 CalendarIntegration[6095:1303] Assigned identifier: C5FD3792-EBF1-4766-B27D-2767E5C8F3BE
2013-01-13 10:32:52.043 CalendarIntegration[6095:1303] NOT FOUND
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According the doc, this behavior is as expected, [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2),

> A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetch-able by caching its other properties.